# .Net 4.0 Web application gridviews edit,delete operation is not working on IE 11 if compatibility mode is off

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, gridview, internet-explorer-11

I am Developing a web application ASP.net 4.0.  I used update panel and under the update panel I used a gridview control. This works fine in all browsers except IE11 x86 on windows 7.

In IE11 If Compatibility mode is ON then its working fine means all operations of the gridview controls are working (edit,update,delete etc). But when Postback causes,  it displays the blank page before going to next control.

If Compatibility mode is off then gridview operation is not working (browsers doesn't allow to edit or delete the record) but when postback is caused it doesn't displaying blank page before going to next control.

I downloaded a patch of .net framework 4.0 from below link and installed. But it did  not work for me.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39257

I also tried including “App_Browsers” folder in my application but this is not working.

So how can I implement the gridview's edit, delete event without having compatibility mode on in IE 11.

Visual studio:2010
.Net framework:4.0
IE Version:11.0.9600.17126
OS:windows 7, 32 bit

Note:Web application is working fine in mozila 27.0.1 ,chrome  etc

Answer (score 0):

Are you receiving any Javascript errors?  We had a similar issue, turned on the doPostBack method was not generated, so we fixed it following this:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IE10AndIE11AndWindows81AndDoPostBack.aspx

Comment: thanks I had similar error which you got and I resolved this error installing .net framework patch(NDP40-KB2836939-v3-x86) as you had done. But still unable to  implement gridview's edit, delete event.

Comment: I included below meta tag under head section which now  allows Edit, Delete button excution the event. So thr' code I am setting compatible mode ON.

 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />

But still I see blank page after postback if I run my application on IE browser 8 , 11. I plan to post a separate query for blank page issue, it is there in IE 8 as well.